# SSIS getdate into DateTimeOffset column - data value overflowed the type

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, datetimeoffset

I have an SSIS package.  The source is a SQL query.  The destination is a table.  The package worked until I changed a column in a destination table from datetime to datetimeoffset(0).

Now, all records fail with a "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the type used by the provider" error on this particular column.

The value in the source query is getdate().  I tried TODATETIMEOFFSET(getdate(),'-05:00') without success.

In fact, the only thing that has worked so far is to hard code the following into the source query:

```
cast('3/14/12' as datetime)
```

The only other interesting piece of information is that the package worked fine when running the source query against another server implying that maybe a setting is involved - but I see no obvious differences between the two servers.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I found that doing what was listed here helped: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/8d097a17-af40-417f-9ab2-add67bf5468c. I made an explicit format for use in a derived column. Pain to do but it appears that there are some odd things happening in SSIS with dateTime elements.

Comment: What is the column's data type in the data flow? Right click on the path out of the source query and select Metadata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest to add a "data conversion component" to deal with it, but since you changed only on the destination, it means that you can change your source query to do:

```
select cast(YOUR_DATE_COLUMN as datetimeoffset(0))
```

Comment: We eventually settled on this.  I found that the precision of the source was too high with getdate() - if I hard-coded a value with milliseconds it failed too.  Still not sure why the old method worked on one server and not another - but explicitly casting it to datetimeoffset(0) worked.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking, we found an alternative solution that works if the source is in SQL 2005 (no support for datetimeoffset).

```
select dateAdd(minute,datediff(minute,0,getutcdate()),0)
```

The intent is to reduce the precision.  Granted I also lose seconds but if I try the above line with seconds I get an overflow error.